# gzip compression with action filter not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compression, gzip, action-filter

I am using a actionfilter to gzip compress my responses from actions inside controlers

This is my action filter:

```
Public Class CompressAttribute 
        Inherits ActionFilterAttribute 
        Implements IActionFilter 
        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext) 
            Dim request As HttpRequestBase = filterContext.HttpContext.Request 

            Dim acceptEncoding As String = request.Headers("Accept-Encoding") 

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding) Then 
                Return 
            End If 
            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant() 

            Dim response As HttpResponseBase = filterContext.HttpContext.Response 
            If acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE") Then 

                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate") 

                response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding") 
                response.Filter = New WebCompressionFilter(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress) 

            ElseIf acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP") Then 
               response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip") 
                response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding") 
                response.Filter = New WebCompressionFilter(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress) 
            End If 
        End Sub 
    End Class
```

I apply it to the actions inside my controlers.

The problem is that it works just fine on my desktop in development environment but on my live server (in shared hosting) it does not gzip encode.

Instead it does chunked transfer encoding....

Why?

this is my responses:

**development environment:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0

Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 04:12:29 GMT

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

p3p: CP=\'NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM\'

X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0

Content-Encoding: gzip

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 13411

Connection: Close
```

**live server:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

p3p: CP=\'NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM\'

X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 04:13:09 GMT

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

X-OSSProxy: OSSProxy 1.3.331.322 (Build 331.322 Win32 en-us)(Oct 11 2011 17:53:42)

Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are trying to do this manually in your own code? This functionality already exists in IIS:

Make sure you have [installed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738113%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) Dynamic Content Compression on the machine (bullet 5 in the link) and [enabled it in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). I have never had any issues with it once these steps are completed. Once you do this there is also no need to have your attribute anymore, IIS will handle it for you implicitly on both static and dynamic content. Less code to maintain is always a good thing!